# leetcode 14 Longest Common Prefix Java substring equivalent in python

Tags: python-3.x, find, substring

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

Example 1:

Input: ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"
Example 2:

Input: ["dog","racecar","car"]
Output: ""
Explanation: There is no common prefix among the input strings.
Note:

All given inputs are in lowercase letters a-z.]

My current solution works is to:

```
the algo here is to take the first element in the list and compare it to the other elements

if the prefixes are different, then reduce the word from the end

flower vs flow => reduce r from flower

flowe vs flow => reduce e from flowe

flow vs flow => the same. stop
```

And it is working for this test case:

## Input: ["flower","flow","flight"]

## Output: "fl"

```
class Solution:

    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:




        if len(strs) == 0:

            return ""

        prefix = strs[0]

        for i in range(1,len(strs), 1):

            while (strs[i].find(prefix) != 0): # use the function "find" to compare the next word "strs[i] and 'prefix'. If any difference, return the number of element that is different 

                prefix=prefix[:-i]

        return prefix
```

But it will fail in the test case ["abab","aba","abc"]

Output:
"a"

Expected:
"ab"

It is because the find won't work when the prefix is longer than the other elements and return -1

```
>>> prefix='abab'
>>> strs='aba'
>>> strs.find(prefix)
-1
```

I am wondering if there is any Java equivalent function "substring" in python that will work?

This Java solution works with "substring"

```
class Solution {
    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
        if (strs.length == 0) return "";
        String prefix = strs[0];
        for (int i=1; i<strs.length; i++)
        {
            while (strs[i].indexOf(prefix) !=0)

            {
                prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length()-1);

            }

        }

        return prefix;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in python, you can just use the start index and end index to get the substring. 
Like: val[1:3]

Answer (score 0):

use a dataframe and iloc to slice the resulting rows for string segments of the data value. check where the resulting set is 1 meaning the slice are all duplicates and add them to a list.  find the max sized string in the list.

```
data=['flower','flow','flight']
min_length=min([len(x) for x in data])
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['data'])    
results=[]    
for i in range(1,min_length):
   alist=[]
   alist=(df.iloc[0:min_length]['data'].str[0:i])

   if len(set(alist))==1:
          results.append(set(alist))
 print(max([x.pop() for x in results],key=len))
```

output

```
fl
```